# Catch an exception of an asynchronous called SQL-Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I call **asynchrounously** some stored procedures with **BeginExecuteNonQuery** and **EndExecuteNonQuery** (in C#). How can I catch the (defined) exceptions of these stored procedures in the C# program? Or does the try{}catch{} also works for asynchrounous calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any exception with severity above 10 raised in the procedure execution that was returned to the client (ie. not swallowed by `BEGIN TRY`/`BEGIN CATCH`) will be raised as a SqlException in the moment you invoke `EndExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Any errors raised during a stored procedure will surface in .NET as a `SqlException` with an error number.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this will help but i've used this method to catch SP exceptions from C# before

```
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/Catchexceptionwhencallingstoredprocedure.htm
```